# How to insert data into a table in a postgresql database using prisma?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

My question will be brief. I use prisma to manage my postgresql database. I would like to insert objects into a table in my database from my prisma file. So I inserted the following code:

```
INSERT INTO "User" ("firstName","email","password") VALUES ("Stephie","goune3@gmail.com","affaires")
```

this gave me the following error:

```
Error: Get config: Schema Parsing P1012

error: Error validating: This line is invalid. It does not start with any known Prisma schema keyword.
  -->  schema.prisma:57
   | 
56 | 
57 | INSERT INTO "User" ("firstName","email","password") VALUES ("Stephie","goune3@gmail.com","affaires")
58 | 
   | 

Validation Error Count: 1
```

So I replaced the double quotes with the single quotes, but it still gave me the same error. I can't find much about it on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using Prisma wrong way, schema file is only for defining database model, it can't execute raw SQL statement. If you want to insert initial data to table, use [seeding feature](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/seed-database).